# What's the purpose of setting a file's owner for the launch screen in Swift?

Tags: swift, screen, xcode6, launch, iboutlet

In Xcode 6 with Swift it seems that you can set a class and a module for the launch screen. Also you can set outlets like labels, but if I try to create a property with the outlet, the issue navigator shows "Illegal configuration. Launch screens may not have connections". So my question is:

What's the purpose of setting the file's owner class for this screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Screen is a just Static Plain design view. iOS8 give you opportunity to design splash screen with your own way (Reduce designer cost and time!!!!!). You can not change it's value at run time. As per my Understand, If you create a connection with your UIViewcontroller or any other class then you can change it's value at run time. So Launch screen has a plain .xib nothing else. If you need more help then let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what's the aim of the plain .xib file, but then why can you set the file's owner? Thinking about that, perhaps is the normal behaviour of .xibs files and in this special case you shouldn't set the file's owner on .xib launch screen. Am I right?

Comment: @jomafer you are absolutely right.As per my understand our xib is a simply part of MVC.If you create file owner then it's create a instance object and you can access and change it's value run time.If you can not create then you can not change its value. iOS into not change behavior of .xib but just simply like put condition if it's a Launch screen object then you can not create file's owner or instance out side view. Sorry for bad English and long explanation. It's my point of view.Thanks!